# Xamarin: IsDebuggerConnected returns incorrect value

Tags: android, xamarin

This picture is self explanatory I think.

[image: What the?]

Anyone know why this might be happening, and if I can fix it?

Comment: You probably want to use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`

Comment: I would say that is broke, `Dalvik.SystemInterop.VMDebug.IsDebuggerConnected` has the same problem... (Xamarin.Android Version: 6.0.1.9), as I am using AS to debug NDK code and profile GPU...  Fill a bug  @ https://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: I'd expect that `Android.OS.Debug.IsDebuggerConnected` would probably return true when a Java debugger is connected to the process rather than the mono debugger.

Comment: @SushiHangover I've filed a bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38241

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Android.OS.Debug.IsDebuggerConnected` **only** returns true when the process has the Java/jdb debugger connected. Use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached` to detect when Mono/Xamarin Studio debugger is connected..

You can verify the above statement with the following steps:

### 1.

Create a new Xamarin.Android app named *DebugTest* with the following source code:

```
[Activity (Name="com.companyname.debugtestapp.MainActivity", Label = "DebugTestApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate {
            string androidConnected = Android.OS.Debug.IsDebuggerConnected ? "JDB Debugger" : "";
            string monoConnected = System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached ? "Mono Debugger" : "";
            button.Text = "Debugging mode: " + androidConnected + " | " + monoConnected;
        };
    }
}
```

Some important things to note:

- Override the default name of the activity using `Name=com.companyname.debugtestapp.MainActivity` so it doesn't use the MD5 sum of the assembly name ([Explained here](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1/#Android_Callable_Wrapper_Naming)).
- The button will display if it detects the debugger that is connected. Either JDB or Mono.

### 2.

Start debugging the app via Xamarin Studio. Click the button to see:

"Debugging mode:  | Mono Debugger"

This means we have detected the *Mono* debugger.

### 3.

Kill the app.

### 4.

Connect the Java debugger to the app via the following set of terminal commands:

```
# Start the main activity via adb. This will open it in debug mode, meaning it will wait until a debugger is connected before proceeding.
adb -d shell am start -D -n "com.companyname.debugtestapp/com.companyname.debugtestapp.MainActivity"
# Discover the Java Debugger port. Copy the number outputted here...
adb jdwp
# Forward the debugger port to JDB. Replace '7602' with the port number outputted by the command above.
adb forward tcp:8000 jdwp:7602
# Start the Java debugger...
jdb -attach 127.0.0.1:8000
```

You should see:

```
Initializing jdb ...
>
```

This specifies the Java debugger is connected.

On your phone, click the button. You should see the text **Debugging mode: JDB Debugger | **.